# Shore up stone foundation cap at house sill

Tags: masonry

I need to shore up the crown of a quarry/limestone foundation where the foundation meets the sill.  This sill runs parallel to the floor joists and most of the damage is located between two windows.

I was going about a repointing project and started clearing loose mortar at the crown.  However what I found was most of the mortar at the crown was deteriorating, and the stone was removed quite easily.  There appeared to be no pressure on this part of the stone.

I would consider mortaring the existing stone, however this is far deeper than is advised for repointing and I would like some consulting on the best course of action.  Attached are pictures.

The sill level appears to go leaning slightly away from the house between the two windows.  On the opposite corner near the crawl space, it is leveled towards the house.  Further inspection also reveals the sill is not sitting on the main carrying beam - I'm not sure if it was ever intended to do so, however.

I've attached some images of the cavities and the levels and the initial report that was sent when the house was first inspected.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best bet here would probably be to place temporary shoring to support the sill in some way. Then remove the crumbly foundation and repair/replace it. Once that is done you can remove the temporary shoring.

But that being said you may want to look into what actually caused the issue? Was it just that the mortar used was not mixed correctly? Was it not given time to cure before pressure was added? Or... is there maybe a drainage issue, seen that the damage is very localized, or something similar that needs to be resolved so that this doesn't happen again in future?